# wlan0: deauthenticated from <ip6> (Reason: 2)

Tags: 12.04, networking, dell, intel-wireless, xps

Previous questions on that topic didn't really help, therefore a new one.

**Problem**

Every time I try to connect to the wifi, I get automatically "deauthenticated" (reason: 2)

**Theories on the web**

1. Multiple drivers are used. But I can't see that it applies to me.
2. It has do something with the "CRDA"

**My System + background**

Dell XPS 13 with 12.02 preinstalled. I managed to crash my system two days ago (also wifi problems, no wifi was detected at all) and because I couldn't fix it, I thought I just use the Dell recovery mode. No I am able to see wifi, but I get kicked out :(

**What I tried**

1. I changed this "crda", which was empty before, to "DE", since that is the location I am from. My OS is installed in "EN". -> No improvement
2. I tried to check if 2x drivers are used, but if that is the case, I don't even know where to look :(

**System outputs**

sudo dmesg

```
[ 4205.984379] wlan0: authenticate with f0:7d:68:85:60:ba
[ 4205.985366] wlan0: send auth to f0:7d:68:85:60:ba (try 1/3)
[ 4205.987192] wlan0: authenticated
[ 4205.988751] wlan0: associate with f0:7d:68:85:60:ba (try 1/3)
[ 4205.991531] wlan0: RX AssocResp from f0:7d:68:85:60:ba (capab=0xc31 status=0 aid=1)
[ 4205.993986] wlan0: associated
[ 4205.994624] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: GB
[ 4205.997616] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: GB
[ 4205.997618] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 4205.997620] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[ 4205.997622] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[ 4205.997623] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[ 4205.997624] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm)
[ 4209.008415] wlan0: deauthenticated from f0:7d:68:85:60:ba (Reason: 2)
[ 4209.010142] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 4209.015212] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 4209.015219] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 4209.015224] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300  mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 4209.015228] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 4209.015232] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 4209.015235] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 4209.015238] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 4209.015258] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: DE
[ 4209.021947] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: DE
[ 4209.021950] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 4209.021952] cfg80211:   (2400000 KHz - 2483500 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[ 4209.021954] cfg80211:   (5150000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[ 4209.021955] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5350000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[ 4209.021957] cfg80211:   (5470000 KHz - 5725000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2698 mBm)


lspci -nnk | grep -i net -A2

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:08b1] (rev 6b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:c470]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

uname -a

```
Linux luken 3.5.0-41-generic #64somerville8-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 2 09:57:33 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

less /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

ifconfig

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:3752 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3752 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:304256 (304.2 KB)  TX bytes:304256 (304.2 KB)

lxcbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a6:0f:13:82:6a:60  
          inet addr:10.0.3.1  Bcast:10.0.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a40f:13ff:fe82:6a60/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:70 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:11439 (11.4 KB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2a:ce:cc:31:31:19  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e8:b1:fc:2a:4b:a8  
          inet6 addr: fe80::eab1:fcff:fe2a:4ba8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:197 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:195 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:22261 (22.2 KB)  TX bytes:30225 (30.2 KB)
```

iwconfig

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

virbr0    no wireless extensions.

lxcbr0    no wireless extensions.

wlan0     no wireless extensions.
```

rfkill list

```
1: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Have you tried disabling IPV6?  If that doesn't help, can you [look here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and post the output?

Comment: Oh, I did quite some research, but I never stumbled upon that page :( 
Actually, I saw on launchpad some discussion which suggested that is not really a problem of Ubuntu, but of either the Kernel or the Intel Wifi Driver. Therefore, I upgraded to 14.10 and the problem is now fixed.  Something else about my previous situation: Wifi's without authentication worked just fine.

I guess I write a reply soon (just a bit busy) about my findings. Not really a perfect answer, but still better than nothing.